# SQL (Persons share the same birthday but they are exactly 100 years older or younger)

Tags: sql, oracle

i have this table:

```
name     dob
Peter  1914-07-23
John   1990-03-25
Sandra 2014-07-23
Sam    1911-01-01
Jane   2011-01-01
Tom    2017-01-01
```

How do I fetch a list of Persons who have the same dob and exactly 100 years older or younger?

Expected rows:

```
name   dob
Peter  1914-07-23
Sandra 2014-07-23
Sam    1911-01-01
Jane   2011-01-01
```

The difference between dob should be 100 years

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the DOB is a date data type, would suggest using `TRUNC` and `ADD_MONTHS`.

```
SELECT a.name
FROM my_table a,
     my_table b
WHERE TRUNC(a.dob) = TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(b.dob, 100*12))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to convert the DOB to just the month and day, and then do a group  by on that to find any having more than 1. In other words:

```
select to_char(dob, 'MM-DD') as birthday
from mytable
group by to_char(dob, 'MM-DD')
having count(*) > 1
```

This should give you all the dupes. Then you can ask for everyone with one of those birthdays:

```
select name, dob
from mytable
where to_char(dob, 'MM-DD') in (
    select to_char(dob, 'MM-DD') as birthday
    from mytable
    group by to_char(dob, 'MM-DD')
    having count(*) > 1
)
```

It might not be the fastest, but it seems the most intuitive to me.

Edit: In rereading the question and the answers, I am not convinced I understood correctly. But I am thinking that none of these answers is exactly what you wanted, so maybe you will have to combine them all to get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

`select * from persons where MONTH(dob) = 07 and Day(dob) = 23 ;`